# Gulp exits too early

Tags: javascript, gulp

There's simple gulpfile but it doesn't executes as expected:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var mapStream = require('map-stream');
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('123.js')
        .pipe(log('before'))
        .pipe(rename({prefix: '_'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
        .pipe(log('after'))
    ;
});

function log (txt) {
    return mapStream(function (file, cb) {
        console.log(txt, fs.statSync(file.path).size, !!file.contents.toString());
        cb();
    });
}
```

logs only "before", but no "after". why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to returning the stream as Sindre suggested, you need to pass 'file' to the callback function of 'map-stream' in order to pass the data through the stream.

```
function log (txt) {
    return mapStream(function (file, cb) {
        console.log(txt, fs.statSync(file.path).size, !!file.contents.toString());
        cb(null, file);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [return the stream](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#return-a-stream):

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('123.js')
        .pipe(log('before'))
        .pipe(rename({prefix: '_'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
        .pipe(log('after'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But still it logs the same, before only.